# Method isn't being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, stripe-payments

I am trying to process card payments with Stripe but im struggling with the basic rails stuff, I am a novice. I cant get the controller to use the method "save_with_payment", its skips and redirect with the error notice. The form is on the events show page and I have a registrations model to handle the payment. Apologies for the incorrect indents I am still getting the hang of this. 1 other mistake is that the redirect goes to the event index page and not the show page. Very confused.

### Model

```
class Registration
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :address 
  field :email
  field :job_title
  field :company
  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :postcode
  field :stripe_card_token
  field :stripe_customer_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
     amount: 40000,
     currency: "gbp",
     card: stripe_card_token,
     description: email
    })
    save
   end
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  end

end
```

### Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @event = Event.all
  end 

  def show
     @event = Event.where(:slug => params[:slug]).first
     @registration = Registration.new
  end

  def payment
    @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])
     if @registration.save_with_payment(@event)
      redirect_to events_path(@event), :notice => "Thank you for registering for"
     else
      redirect_to events_path(@event), :notice => "We're sorry, something went wrong"
     end
  end
end
```

### Routes

```
match 'registration' => 'events#show', :via => :get
match 'registration' => 'events#payment', :via => :post
match '/:slug' => "events#show"
```

### View

```
<%= simple_form_for [@registration], :method => :post, :url => registration_path do |f| %>
<%= f.input :first_name %>
<%= f.input :last_name %>
<%= f.input :email %>
<%= f.input :job_title %>
<%= f.input :company %>
<%= f.input :stripe_card_token, as: :hidden %>
<div class="input card_number">
    <label for="card_number">Card number</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number %>
</div>
<div class="input card_cvc">
    <label for="card_code">Security code (CVC)</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_cvc %>
</div>
<div class="input card_dates">
    <label>Card expiration date</label>
    <%= select_month nil, { add_month_number: true }, { id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil, { add_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 15 }, { id: "card_year"} %>
</div>
<%= f.button :submit, "Register", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your method last line is false and it always returns false

Answer (score 0):

How to you know it skips your method?. There is probably an exception.  Raise the exception in your rescue block.

```
def save_with_payment
    if valid?
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
     amount: 400.00,
     currency: "gbp",
     card: stripe_card_token,
     description: email
    })
    save
   end
   rescue Exception => e
    raise e
    false
  end
```

Comment: I know it skips the method because it goes to the else statement and displays this notice - We're sorry, something went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at your server log for the exception. It will in your #{root_path}/log/<environment>.log

Comment: Also, going to else statement means save_with_payment returned false(in the case of an exception)

Comment: This method is not called so there is no exception rasied. Here is the log file anyway - Started POST "/registration" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-08 22:14:05 +0100
Processing by EventsController#payment as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3qz44RBQO+SEfg7X8XaWmhVREEFi1P/qCHRutlfeSvk=", "registration"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "job_title"=>"", "company"=>"", "stripe_card_token"=>""}, "card_number"=>"4242424242424242", "card_cvc"=>"123", "date"=>{"month"=>"1", "year"=>"2014"}}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events
Completed 302 Found in 2ms

Comment: Is your Registration record valid? if not the return value of your method is going to be nil which is false

Comment: Yes the record is correct, there is no validation on the other details. This is the way Stripe payments work.